# Colour a cell range based on another cell's value?

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to write a statement in MS Excel 2013 that does the following:

`If cell E3 = "N/A"`, make the background colour of cell range F3:N3 = black

`If cell E3 = anything else`, do nothing

Some sort of conditional formatting? I tried a few options but couldn't get it going? :(

Any suggestions?

Comment: My pleasure @Courtenay Lee Shoy.  Don't forget to vote up an answer if you found it helpful, and accept one if it answers your question so the rest of the community can learn from it.  Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select cells F3 to N3. On the Home Ribbon click Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to....

Use this formula

`=isna($e3)`

Note the placement of the $ sign. Select the Format button and apply a format. Confirm all dialogs.

Comment: The `ISNA()` formula returns true/false if the value refers to "#N/A", not "N/A".

Comment: Daniel - thank you for the clarification re: the"#" - I was wondering why the conditional format was not being applied.
telyyn - thank you also for the response. I can use "#NA" instead of "N/A" so your solution works nicely.

Comment: My pleasure.  Also, on SO the best way to say "thanks" is to vote up and/or accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do this with Excel VBA (as per your question tags), then you can use the `Interior.Color` property of a cell range:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("F3:N3").Interior.Color = RGB(0,0,0)
```

If you need to clear the background if cell E3 is not "N/A" then use

```
ActiveSheet.Range("F3:N3").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
```